# A conjecture on a Subset Power Sum Problem motivated by Computer Science

Tags: co.combinatorics, nt.number-theory, computational-complexity

Let $X=\{x_{1}, \cdots , x_{n}\}$ be a set of $n$ positive integers and integer $i \ge 1$. Let’s say that the set $X$ is $i$-sum-avoiding if for any nonnegative integers $c_{1}, \cdots, c_{n}$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{n}c_{j} = n$ and $(c_{1},\cdots, c_{n}) \ne (1,\cdots, 1)$, it holds that

$\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n}c_{j}x_{j}^{i} \ne \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{j}^{i}$

Let $f(n,i)$ be the minimum value for a given $i \ge 1$ such that there exists an $i$-sum-avoiding set $X$ consisting of $n$ positive integers at most $f(n,i)$. Does there exist a constant $k_{i}$ for every $i$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb N$, it holds $f(n,i) \le n^{k_{i}}$? If it does, what is the minimum of such $k_{i}$ for every $i$?

Showing such a set would help solve hard problems in computer science given some space relaxations. It seems that the hardness of such problems is directly related to non-existence of such sets. I could only show such sets when $k=n$ that is $k$ is not a constant. My example for $X$ is $X = \{n^{1}, n^{2},\cdots, n^{n}\}$.

$\underline{Conjecture}$: $k_{i} = \infty$ $\forall i \ge 1$.

Comment: I find the statement of the problem very confusing. So long as $S$ is not identical to $N_n$, there will be some $i\ge1$ such that the sums in (1) are unequal. But maybe that is not what you are asking. 

Comment: Two problems: first, a *set* does not have duplicate elements, by definition it cannot have duplicate elements.  An "ordered list" or a "multiset" can have duplicate elements. Second, you are almost defining something basic.  $3^2+4^2=5^2$ is an example for $i=2$, so the multisets {1,2,3,4,5} and {1,2,5,5} work for $i=2$, but obviously not for $i \ne 2$.  What's your motivation for this problem?  Is this part of a homework problem-set?  Please see the FAQ in that instance.

Comment: If I find such a set, I can solve some of the hardest problems in computer science given some space relaxations. It seems that the hardness is directly related to non-existence of such sets.

Comment: then please spell out one example of these hard problems that you can solve, and how ?

Comment: @sleepless in beantown: I agree that the first point is problematic.  As for the second point, your example shows that the set {1,2,3,4,5} does _not_ satisfy the condition for i=2.

Comment: @sleepless in beantown: Now I see that your comment referred to an older revision of the question.

Comment: @Suresh Venkat Consider any other subset $S$ of size $n$ that has property (1) and (2) but violates $(3)$. Calculate the total number of such sets. You will see where I am getting at.

Comment: @Suresh Venkat space relaxation is the key word. I don't think it provides efficient techniques from a space perspective. But it provides a direct method from a time perspective. So most likely the answer may only be of some theoretical interest.

Comment: @Suresh Venkat "...total number of such unordered sets"

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito, thanks for noticing my two points.  The question is a moving target; but I like it when the questioner takes the effort to correct their mistakes and clarify their points.  I'm going to look at your answer below and see if I can find something more to say.

Comment: wow, the latest rewrite in terms of $i$-sum-avoiding is even more confusing to me.  You (unknown (google), at least give yourself a nickname or name) are using $i$ as a given, as an iterating variable over a sum, and using the given $i$ as the power of the exponent.  *Please* expound upon what hard problems in computer science this might help with.  How did you come up with this problem?

Comment: @sleepless fixed the i issue. The question is written from Tsuyoshi's statement of the problem

Comment: $i$-sum refers to $i$ being used as power

Comment: @unknown-google'r / user 10035 : thanks for the rewrite again.  I'm going to re-read it with a fresh mind and attack it again a little later today.  Thanks, sincerely, for reading the comments and updating the question.  Also, any more background about the computer science implications would also be of interest to me, if you'd care to share...

Comment: You should “unaccept” my post.  Accepting an answer means that you are satisfied with the answer and that you do not need more answers.  I merely rewrote your question, and the question has not been answered at all!

Comment: Actually I prefer to have it to myself except telling you the fact that this is a nice way to capture the symmetric group.

Comment: Thank you for improving the wording of the question.  I deleted my post because it has been incorporated in the question.  The question is interesting (to me at least), and I hope that someone can answer it!

Comment: Every positive integer can be written as a sum of 4 squares, so every positive integer can be written as a sum of 8 squares in lots of ways. Similar remarks apply to cubes, 4th powers, whatever. I think your intuition about growth rates is flawed. 

Comment: Thank you very much. I will remove my thoughts. So there is no easy answer then to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I think proves that for any *i*, there is no constant *k*<sub>*i*</sub> satisfying *f*(*n*,*i*)≤*n*<sup>*k*<sub>*i*</sub></sup>.  That is:

**Claim**.  Let *i* be a positive integer.  Then the function *f*(*n*,*i*) is not polynomially bounded in *n*.

**Proof**.  First consider the case of *i*=1.  A key observation is that if *X*={*x*<sub>1</sub>,…,*x*<sub>*n*</sub>} contains two subsets *A* and *B* such that |*A*|=|*B*|, *A*≠*B*, and the sum of *A* is equal to the sum of *B*, then *X* cannot be 1-sum-avoiding since assigning *c*<sub>*j*</sub> as follows violates the condition: *c*<sub>*j*</sub>=2 if *x*<sub>*j*</sub> belongs to *A* but not to *B*, *c*<sub>*j*</sub>=0 if *x*<sub>*j*</sub> belongs to *B* but not to *A*, and *c*<sub>*j*</sub>=1 if neither holds.

Let *m* be a positive integer and *X* be a 1-sum-avoiding set of size 2*m*.  By the above observation, all *m*-element subsets of *X* must have distinct sums, and therefore the largest sum must be at least $\binom{2m}{m}$.  Therefore, the largest element in *X* must be at least $\binom{2m}{m}/m>2^{m-1}$, which implies that *f*(2*m*,1) > 2<sup>*m*−1</sup>.  This establishes the claim for *i*=1.

Now observe that if a set *X*={*x*<sub>1</sub>,…,*x*<sub>*n*</sub>} is *i*-sum-avoiding, then the set {*x*<sub>1</sub><sup>*i*</sup>,…,*x*<sub>*n*</sub><sup>*i*</sup>} is 1-sum-avoiding.  This means that *f*(*n*,1) ≤ *f*(*n*,*i*)<sup>*i*</sup>.  Since we already know that *f*(*n*,1) is not polynomially bounded, *f*(*n*,*i*) is not polynomially bounded in *n*, either.  **QED**.

Answer (score 1):

I still find the statement of the problem very confusing. For $i=1$, you want your set $X$ to be a non-averaging set, that is, a set containing no three distinct elements $a,b,c$ such that $a+b=2c$. You want more than that, but that's a start, and there's enough literature on non-averaging sets to give you some kind of lower bound on $k$.

Tsuyoshi Ito posted an answer while I was typing mine, you'll see we're thinking along similar lines.

EDIT: There are several sections of Guy's Unsolved Problems In Number Theory that discuss problems not exactly what you want but not a million miles removed, either, and some of the references given there may be useful. Problem C8 is sets with distinct sums of subsets, C11 is three-subsets with distinct sums, C14 is maximal sum-free sets, C16 is nonaveraging sets.

Comment: … except that I did not realize the connection of the question to non-averaging sets until I read your answer!  The connection is interesting.  Because of the way the value $k_i$ is defined, considering the non-averaging condition alone indeed gives some lower bound on the value of $k_1$.  However, unfortunately the best lower bound on f(n,1) we can hope for from this method is $n^{1+o(1)}$ because there is a “large” non-averaging set (Behrend _PNAS_ 1946 http://www.pnas.org/content/32/12/331.full.pdf+html), whereas we do not know if f(n,1) is polynomially bounded or not.

Answer (score -1):

Take $x_j=2^{i-1}$. I claim that if $\sum_{j=1}^n c_j 2^{j-1} = \sum_{j=1}^n 2^{j-1}$ with $\sum_{j=1}^n c_j\leq n$, then $c_j=1$ for all $j$. The case $n=1$ is easy. In general note that $c_1$ is odd. We substract 1 on both sides of the equation and divide by 2, replace $c_2$ by $c_2+\frac{c_1-1}{2}$, and finally shift all indices by 1. Then we obtain an equation of the same form as before for a smaller value of $n$, and are done by induction. The same argument shows that $\{1, 2, 4, 8, \ldots\}$ is $i$-sum avoiding for every $i$, however, for larger $i$ there should be more efficient choices.